# Excel VBA - How to increase the value after every 12 months

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**
I am trying to calculate monthly cashflows over a given period (based on start and end dates). My VBA code already generates the list of the months between start and end dates as shown in the screenshot.

**Issue:**
I am trying to calculate salary income (hypothetical) over the period. The problem is that the salary should only increase after every 12 months from the previous change date. Otherwise it should remain equal to the salary of the previous month.

An extract of my final target outcome is shown in the image:

- My cashflow projects are from today's date (start date in cell B4) whereas the most recent salary to be used could have been applicable before that (refer cell B3). As such the salary should only increase every 12 months from Salary date and not start date.
- if the salary does not increase, then it should be equal to the previous month salary and not the original salary in cell B1.

[Calculation required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KARVk.jpg)

Comment: This is not a coding service where you state your requirements and get back ready-to-run debugged code. 
You need to put in some efforts yourself. Show us what you have tried this far.
Also read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
For i = 13 to 180 Step 12
         Range("C" & i &":C" & i + 12) = Range("C" & i - 12) * (1+ Range("B2"))
        Next i
```